# Work with arrays in a multi inner-join-table sql query

Tags: sql, arrays, loops

I've got the following SQL query which works perfectly.

```
SELECT u.*,  
(pag1.id is not null) as InPage1, 
(pag2.id is not null) as InPage2,
(pag3.id is not null) as InPage3,

FROM table u left outer join  

page1 pag1  on u.id = pag1.id left outer join  
page2 pag2  on u.id = pag2.id left outer join 
page3 pag3  on u.id = pag3.id left outer join 

WHERE 

pag1.id = $num OR
pag2.id = $num OR
pag3.id = $num
```

The point is that I'd like to make this query extracting table data from an array. I explain  myself:

I've got an array which contains all data used in the sql query (in this case its size is 3 but could be any size) :

```
$array = array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "pag1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "page1"
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(7) "InPage1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "pag2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "page2"
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(7) "InPage2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "pag3"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "page3"
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(7) "InPage3"
  }
```

So , I'm (unluckily) trying to execute this sql query using data from this array. 
Any ideas of how would this be done?

Comment: how have you tried to do this?

Comment: I don't really know in what way perform. I tried doing a IN in the WHERE part passing the array.